# I am trying to write a JAVA program that finds nested loops in a JAVA file stored at a specified loation

Tags: java, regex

```
class LoopDetector {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
         String line;
         boolean found = false;

        int loopCounter = 0 ;

          FileReader fr=new FileReader("D:\\Mi\\Workspace\\Test.java"); 
             //Test.java is the java file containing the code to be checked
              BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);   
                //ArrayList<String> w= new ArrayList<String>(); 
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();                 
         // int x=0;
          while((line=br.readLine()) != null)  {
          sb.append(line);
          //    x++     ;     
          }
          String readFile = sb.toString();
          //String[] lineByLine = readFile.split("\\n");
          String pattern = "((for|if|while).*{(.|\n)[^}]*(for|if|while))";
          found = Pattern.matches(pattern,readFile);
          if ( !found ) {
              System.out.println("Nested loops found in file"); }
          else {
              System.out.println("No Loop Found In file");
          }     
    }       
}
```

Now when I run this I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 16

((for|if|while). * {(.|)[^}]*(for|if|while))

                 ^  (error at Location of "*")

    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Unknown Source)
    at com.nestedloopdetection.LoopDetector.main(LoopDetector.java:30)
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Regular expressions are not the right tool to parse Java (or most other programming languages).

Comment: One issue I can see is that curly brackets are special characters. Change `{` to `[{]` or `\{`

Comment: Your program will not be able to handle comments, or arbitrary levels of {} nesting. Regular expressions cannot handle nesting, and are therefore the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: If this is more than just a regex exercise you should consider a real parser that does the heavy lifting for you. There are full fleged Java grammers available for tools like ANTLR (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR).

Comment: @Henry what approach should I adopt then?

Comment: To do this correctly, you will need a full Java parser, as others have already commented.